# QML Canvas clear image cache

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a `ListView` with a big model and a `Canvas` in the delegate. When scrolling, new delegates are created and deleted as expected, but RAM is not freed. At some point application is killed by iOS because of this.
Neither `QPixmapCache::clear()` nor `QJSEngine::collectGarbage()` nor `QQmlEngine::trimComponentCache()` do any help. Is there a way to free the memory?

Here is a minimal example (can be run with qmlscene). Scroll up and down and see RAM consumption goes up

```
import QtQuick 2.6

ListView {
  width: 320
  height: 480
  model: 1000
  delegate: Canvas {
    id: canvas
    width: parent.width
    height: width

    onPaint: {
      var ctx = getContext("2d")
      ctx.strokeStyle = "red"
      ctx.lineWidth = 2
      ctx.beginPath()
      for (var i = 1; i < 20; ++i) {
        ctx.lineTo(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height);
      }
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
}
```

[QTBUG-59467](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59467)

Comment: Could you post a code example of your delegate for us to help ?

Comment: qtquick is a memory hog, if you are memory constrained and your application loads a lot of data, it is a poor choice.

Comment: @AdrienLeravat added minimal example

Answer (score 0):

Memory consumption is a recurring topic about QtQuick, and you can find some leads and strategies in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html). It improved over time, so the first recommendation is of course to use the most recent version.

Then as for all optimization, I'd recommend having a look at the [QtQuick profiler](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-performance-monitor.html) and/or GammaRay to understand what's causing the high memory usage.

Specifically about ListView, you may want to experiment with the [`cacheBuffer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#cacheBuffer-prop) property of the `ListView`, but to solve your problem you will probably have to lighten your delegates or application, depending on where the problem comes from.

---

EDIT: Apparently in your case, this is a real memory leak, as highlighted by the comments in your ticket [QTBUG-59467](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59467), to be followed !

Comment: `It drastically improved over time` not true based on elaborate testing of very memory demanding applications. 5.8 in particular was supposed to bring memory savings, in reality the same test show about 5% more memory being used compared to 5.7.

Comment: Well it's all relative to the versions you compare, regarding memory usage and management separately. But I get you point, I edited my answer to be more neutral.